# Building CMS on top of CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, content-management-system

Is it possible to build a CMS on top of CodeIgniter where the CMS files is separate from customization files? What I mean is, like CodeIgniter by default comes with 2 main folder, application and system folder. So, all your own files is placed in application folder so that next time you can easily update CodeIgniter by overriding the system folder and everything will still working fine.

So, can I store my files at custom folder? 
E.g.:
system folder - codeigniter
my_system folder - CMS
application folder - All customization on each individual projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use CodeIgniter's native application "Package", you can find the doc here : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html

Answer (score 0):

You can store your file where you want expect system folder as you written. best approach is make folder on root named public or you want and put your file.

Answer (score 0):

system folder contains everything codeigniter needs. application folder contains your specific code - it defaults to showing the welcome page.

consider naming your system folder with the codeigniter version number and date
makes it easier when you are upgrading

and you can easily switch to different versions directly from the index.php page by editing the file path to the folders